# Split multiple cells with multiple lines (in each cell) into individual rows

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

An example of my question is if I have the following cells A1 and A2

**Cell A1:**

Red

White

Blue

**Cell A2:**

Orange

Yellow

Green

How do I get this to automatically transform to:

Cell A1: Red

Cell A2: White

Cell A3: Blue

Cell A4: Orange

Cell A5: Yellow

Cell A6: Green

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with this nested function:

```
=transpose(split(join(char(10),A1:A2),char(10)))
```

to explain:

`char(10)` is the character for a New Line, or a carriage return, which is what is happening when you have all those values in a single cell.

So you use that as the delimiter in your `join` function, which stacks all the cells into a single cell with the same format.

Then use the `char(10)` again to split them all into their own cell.

The `transpose` is the final piece to flip it vertically.

[image]